# c++ comma delimiting/getline

Tags: c++, arrays, delimiter, ifstream

I have a program that needs to take input from a text file with multiple lines. Each line is the information for a student and that information is also separated by commas.

What I have so far is

```
 stringstream ss;
    string data = "";
    string student[50] = "";
    int i = 0;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("file.txt");
        while(getline(inFile, student[i]))
        {

            cout << student[i] << endl;
            i++;
        }
```

Takes each line and assigns it into the student array. Now every student has their own location.

So also I have to break apart the line into each component(name, dob, gpa, address, etc) which will be done in the Student class.

I have this, student variable would be the string of a single line

```
 stringstream ss(student);
    while(getline(ss, data, ',')){
        cout << data << endl;
    }
```

Outputs all the data individually from the file.

Question is: 
How do I change what variable the stringstream will be assigned to in the lower code(the goal isn't to output, I did that for testing to see whats happening), do I have to make data an array and then assign the elements of that array into variables?

Is there a topic relating to delimiter I looked over or don't understand?

Thanks

Comment: bUmp. If anyone can help I would appreciate it. I won't be on for the next hour or so but I will get back to anyone who can help. Thanks again

Comment: What does your `Student` class look like?  If `getline(ss, data, ',')` breaks up your input correctly, you could simply use `getline(ss, studentVar.name ',')` and the rest of the `Student` variables in a loop.

Comment: If you want to reassign the `std::stringstream` you can do: `ss.clear(); ss.str("new string data");`.

Comment: @Namfuak student has all the data variables in the private. The public has an overloaded constructor passing the string gotten from the main. Then that code is applied. What I need it to do is take each part from the string(separated by commas) and assign it to the corresponding variables. Each string will be in the same format.

Comment: ``class Student{
private:
    string fName;
    string lName;
    string gpa;
    string credHours;
public:
    Student(string data){
        stringstream ss(data);
        while(getline(ss, data, ',')){
            cout << data << endl;
        }
    }``

Comment: @Galik is there a way to automatically do it or does that have to be done for however many variables I'm assigning? And is this method called something? No need for either of you to explain it if its easier to redirect me somewhere. Thanks

Comment: I would put it first thing in your `while()` loop. That way you don't need an array to store all the lines. You can process each line into a student record as you read them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reassign the std::stringstream you can do:

```
ss.clear();
ss.str("new string data");
```

I would put it first thing in your while() loop. That way you don't need an array to store all the lines. You can process each line into a student record as you read them.

```
int main()
{
    stringstream ss;
    string data; // no need to initialize
    string student; // no need for array

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("data.txt");

    while(getline(inFile, student))
    {
        cout << student << endl;

        ss.clear(); // clear any errors (from last loop)
        ss.str(student); // put student data in ss

        while(getline(ss, data, ','))
        {
            cout << data << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think for what I need its easier to keep them separate. I will keep what you said in mind, but for now I am using 
``Student *S;
S = new Student[50]; 
``
and then apply my original code to send it directly to the class instead of an array

Comment: @user3562657 Why use new for an array of constant size?

Comment: I'm not aware of another way to do it. Student in that code refers to the class Student

Comment: @user3562657 `Student *S[50];` will initialize a constant size array of size 50 and the compiler will handle deallocation, which means you don't need to remember to delete it.